# does constant convexity assures global minimum

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have the following question: 
Consider a function $f:R^n \longrightarrow R$, s.t.:

1. there is a point $x_0 \in R^n$ s.t. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k} =0$  $\forall k$.
2. the hessian matrix ${\partial^2 f \over \partial x^i \partial x^j}$ is 
   positive definite for all $x \in R^n$ but not necessary constant.

Now, it is the point $x_0$ a global minimizer of $f$ ?? I think yes, but how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Hessian is positive definite then the function is convex. A differentiable convex function satisfies
$f(x)-f(y) \ge Df(y)(x-y)$ for all $x,y$. Hence if $Df(x_0) = 0$, then $x_0$
must be a (global) minimiser.

Proof of above result: Let $\phi(t) = f(y+th)$, then since $\phi$ is convex, we
have $\phi(t)-\phi(0) \le (1-t) \phi(0)+t \phi(1) - \phi(0) = t (\phi(1)-\phi(0))$, and so
${\phi(t)-\phi(0) \over t } \le \phi(1)-\phi(0)$. Taking limits gives
$\phi(1)-\phi(0) \ge \phi'(0)$.

If we let $h = x-y$, and note that $\phi'(0) = Df(y)(y-x)$, we obtain the
desired result.

An similar and very useful result is that the function $R$ defined 
[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) is monotonically non decreasing in either of its variables (with the other fixed).

Comment: Thanks copper.hat. Do you have a formal proof of $f(x) - f(y) \ge D f(y) (x - y)$ ???

Comment: I added some detail above.